# Android very simple online highscore

Tags: android, variables

I basically finished writing my first android app, all thats left is a global highscore.
I want to keep that really simple.

I only want to store one variable online with the highest score, thats it.

My app can then check whether your local score was higher or not and update the variable.

What is the easiest way of doing this?
Do I have to use a mysql database or can I use something more simple for that?

Thank you!

Comment: I think sharedPreferences is enough it is a single item to be stored

Comment: But sharedPreferences aren't stored online, right?

Comment: yes you need to have the service of the particular game or so and we need to send a request to get the data stored over the service

Answer (score 1):

You can check out [scoreninja](http://scoreninja.appspot.com/), [scoreloop](http://www.scoreloop.com/) or [parse](http://www.parse.com).

`scoreninja` or `scoreloop` are probably your best choice.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/) + [Objectify](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/). It's all free.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this very simply with a mySQL database and php. Simply create a database with one field (high Score). Then create a php script that takes the $_GET['score'] variable and compares it with the stored score. If it is higher, store the new score.

Then, you could just call to .../storeScore.php?score=XXXX in your app.

You could easily write another script only for fetching the score.

Here is a good place to start:
http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql/